# "For both of them to go ..."

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the following dialog at a funeral for the parents of two children who died in an accident:

> They were in an accident... For both of them to go... I heard the
>   other person wasn't watching the road.

I don't really sure about the meaning of the sentence: ***"For both of them to go..."***

Is it talking about the cause of the accident in the previous sentence or about the sequence after "they were in an accident"?

Comment: Could you provide some more context?

Comment: There must be another parallel dialogue (on the other end of the phone, say) for this fragment to make sense. eg 'Do you need an ambulance for one of them to go to hospital?'

Comment: @NikhilAnand, the parents of two children died in an accident. This dialog is in the funeral. Some people are talking about it.

Comment: That's what it sounds like. _Go_ is a euphemism for _die_; another is _pass (on)_. Especially at funerals, euphemisms are common for _die_ and _death_.

Comment: The sense is "[How dreadful] for both of them to be killed at once."

Comment: There are words left out but the message is understood: For dealing with the shock of both our children to die at once, I can only repeat what I heard, that the other driver wasn't watching the road.

Comment: It could also mean *for both of them to go [to the destination at the same time].* For example, most corporations have a policy that not all member of the executive staff can travel at the same time—for the very reason that if there's a fatal accident, not all of them will die. It's *likely* that it's a euphemism for death in this case, but since essential words were left out, it's impossible to say with certainty. (With additional context, it could also mean the less likely possibility. For instance, if the two children were seriously ill and *both* parents went somewhere.)

Comment: It's possible the accident occurred because both vehicles or people went at the same time and "for both of them to go" could be describing the circumstances. This is a very morbid guessing game, though.

Answer (score 0):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by H&P (Pages 944-45) says:

> **Clauses with the subordinate form**
>
> [2] i *That it should have come to this!*
>
> ii *To think that he was once the most powerful man in the land!*
>
> The meaning is close to that of the exclamatives *How amazing it is that it should have come to this/ to think that he was once the most powerful man in the land*, with subordinate clauses in extraposed subject function. The subordinate form of the clauses in [2] suggests that, when they stand on their own, as here, they are fragments, containing a subordinate clause but with the matrix frame omitted. Other infinitival constructions that are not overtly embedded include the *Oh to be in England* pattern (which also belongs in the optative category: “I wish I were in England”) and the negative *Not to worry* (“Don’t/ Let’s not worry”), which is rarely found with verbs other than *worry*.

Answer (score -1):

"To go" in this sense means "to die".